# Jquery error after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using an onclick event for the Jquery dialog function...

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() 
{ 
    $("#titleName").on("click",function(e) 
    {            
        $("#userInfo").dialog("open"); 
        e.preventDefault();  
    }) 
})
```

It works fine until I make the ajax call to load one of the divs..

```
$("ul#accordion li a").on('click', function (e) 
{   
    $("#mainContent").load(this.href);  
});
```

After ajax call the `onclick` is throwing this error(twice) ..

> *TypeError : undefined is not a function*

at this line

> $("#userInfo").dialog("open");

The ajax request is bringing in the JQuery library one more time(because of datatables in the request need them).

1) I don't how to avoid loading JQuery twice and at the same time make it to work.

2) I'm not exactly sure, if loading twice is causing the problem.

I've tried using this in both pages but it doesn't work

```
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.4.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Edit:
Actually the answer below fixed the `onclick` issue(looks like JQuery is not loaded twice) But now the data loaded with this request doesn't have any styles or javascript applied.

When I open these requests in a new page they are working fine. But when loaded with ajax request it has only plain data(no styles).

Comment: Did you link to jquery-ui correctly?

Comment: it would be helpful to know which line throws that error. place breakpoints.

Comment: Yes.. I did link it right..all the jquery functions are working fine before the ajax call...

Comment: Daniel.. should I place the breakpoints in the jquery.js ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `TypeError : undefined is not a function` means that `.dialog` is being seen as an undefined element, rather than as a function, which means that you don't have the functions properly imported. You've mentioned that other jQuery functions are working, but the dialog widget is from jQuery UI, rather than the core jQuery library, so you need to make sure you've imported both. If jQuery UI is properly loaded, `.dialog` will be recognized as a function rather than an `undefined`.

However, if you've properly imported both jQuery and jQuery UI, it's likely that, as you suspect, your problem is coming from the reloading of jQuery when your ajax request is called. You can wrap your loading of the script as such to avoid adding it a second time:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>');
}
```

Comment: I can see these scripts in my page source..
<script src="/WarehouseManagementSystem/static/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="/WarehouseManagementSystem/static/js/jquery/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="/WarehouseManagementSystem/static/js/jquery/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

Comment: Edited my comment to add more relevant info. Avoiding importing jQuery twice will likely fix your issue.

Comment: Actually .dialog is also working before the ajax call..  its throws this error after the ajax call. I can still see the reference to the script in the source code..

Comment: Yeah, then it's breaking for sure because of the duplicate loading. I don't know why you've got the strings all escaped and then processing them through unescape -- maybe that's part of the error? I don't know. But the answer definitely lies in not loading jQuery twice -- you're losing your references to the plugins loaded previously.

Comment: If I'm not using unescape the the script tag is getting closed at the first script end tag which is inside the document.write.

Comment: Actually it fixed the onclick issue(looks like jquery is not loaded twice) But now the data loaded with this request doesn't have any styles or javascript applied.  

When I open these requests in a new page they are working fine. But when loaded with ajax request it has only plain data(no styles).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this ??